# Convert Virtualbox image to Hyper-V

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtualbox, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to convert a Virtualbox image to Hyper-V? Preferably without having to startup the virtualbox image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed on our sister site superuser.com before - take a look [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/69351/convert-vdi-to-vhd).

Answer (score 1):

Having problems with the VirtualBox built-in converter (Hyper-V would not open the disks), I had better success with [Disk2vhd from Microsoft SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) - just run the EXE inside the VM you want to migrate.  Detailed instructions at https://hyperv.veeam.com/blog/how-to-convert-physical-machine-hyper-v-virtual-machine-disk2vhd/

- Cons

  - You do need to run the VM in VirtualBox to create the image
  - You get a VSS backup, so after migration the VM didn't get a clean shutdown.
- Pros

  - It's a small utility - no install required
  - It handles multiple spindles
  - You get a .vhdx for each spindle
  - It handles image creation on UNC network path
  - It's blissfully unaware of snapshots - no need to consolidate or clone first.

Once you have the images, attach them to your Hyper-V VM & start it.  The first took a minute, while Windows got used to it's new hardware.

[image]

Comment: Problem is: it's a .exe only, meaning you can only export *Windows* VM...

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot on what's in the image.

As a disclaimer, I know nothing about what VirtualBox tends to install in a guest OS image.  If any of that stuff crashes when VirtualBox isn't present, there's nothing I know of that will help you.

But if your guest OS is Windows Vista or later, you can do quite a bit of servicing off-line, just by mounting the disk image and manipulating it via the OPK tools.  You can install drivers and other components, including the Hyper-V integration components.